# Thermal decomposition of group 2 permanganates

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Do group 2 permanganates produce manganates via thermal decomposition?

Answer (score 2):

It is observed that true composition of alkaline earth metal manganate is not known. I[t is proposed to be a mixture of manganite-manganate and has a general formula, $\ce{R3Mn2O8.H2O}$.](http://calcium.atomistry.com/calcium_manganate.html) However the composition/formula varies according to given method of preparation. It is found on some instance that heating the permangantes of alkaline earth metal gives manganates while in other case it gives manganites.

1. [Mangesium permanagate](http://magnesium.atomistry.com/magnesium_permanganate.html) is prone to decomposition and it explode
   violently in aqueous solution giving oxygen, ozone and the
   manganate?(the reaction product is not defined properly?)
2. Calcium manganate is formed by decomposing [calcium
   permanganate](http://calcium.atomistry.com/calcium_permanganate.html).
3. [Strontium permanaganate](http://strontium.atomistry.com/strontium_permanganate.html) is also prone to decomposition and
   forms either manganite or manganate depending on reaction condition
   but either way, [strontium manganate](http://strontium.atomistry.com/strontium_manganate.html) is formed by heating
   strontium manganite at 1600 °C.
4. [Barium permanganate](http://barium.atomistry.com/barium_permanganate.html) also decomposes at 320 °C to form barium
   manganite but if the permanganate is mixed with barium hydroxide,
   [barium manganate](http://barium.atomistry.com/barium_manganate.html) of composition $\ce{Ba3Mn2O8.H2O}$ is formed.
5. The reaction of beryllium permanganate decomposition is unknown to
   the best of my knowledge mainly due to poor study on the compound.